# Getting an error when trying to connect to the Bigcommerce API with Ruby

Tags: ruby, bigcommerce

I'm new to Ruby and to the BC API so there may be something obvious that I'm missing. When I'm running the following code with the proper details replaced with my store's legacy API credentials:

```
require 'bigcommerce'

Bigcommerce.configure do |config|
  config.auth = 'legacy'
  # You will get this url when registering for an API key
  config.url = ENV['BC_API_ENDPOINT_LEGACY']
  config.username = ENV['BC_USERNAME']
  config.api_key = ENV['BC_API_KEY']
end

puts Bigcommerce::System.time
```

I get the following error:

```
.../lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:882:in `rescue in block in connect': Failed to open TCP connection to :80 (Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 80) (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)
```

I appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

tldr: you're environment variables aren't actually being set :p

Sounds like your environment variables aren't actually being set. 
I say this because the error `Failed to open TCP connection to :80`, does not list any URL, but only the port.

To confirm, within your code, can you simply run:
`puts ENV['BC_API_ENDPOINT_LEGACY']`, and see if anything is printed?

An alternative is to just hardcode your credentials, and not rely on environment variables.

```
Bigcommerce.configure do |config|
  config.auth     = 'legacy'
  config.url      = 'https://url.com'
  config.username = 'api_username'
  config.api_key  = 'api_key'
end
```

FYI, the way you set an environment variable would generally be (from the command line):
`export BC_API_ENDPOINT_LEGACY="https://url.com"` 
And then confirm it is set by `echo $BC_API_ENDPOINT_LEGACY`

You can view [this link](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html) for other options on setting environment variables for your RoR app.